# Make a url to have query parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site which has disable the url rewriting. So I have a problem with query string parameters and I can't enable the gclid parameter for Adwords.

Here is the problem. Ideally the url param should be something like this:

```
http://www.example.com?gclid=test
```

but I take but this:

```
http://www.example.com/gclid/test
```

As I static solution to make the url param work I used this:

```
if (window.location.href === "http://www.example.com") { 
   url = "http://www.example.com?gclid=test"; 
   window.history.pushState("", "", url); 
}
```

Could be possible to make it more dynamic if I know that the query string param is the gclid but its' value is dynamically change?

Comment: Where does the query string value come from?

Comment: @sideroxylon from Adwords

Answer (score 0):

cant you just replace the gclid text with the variable that you receive from Adwords like this?

```
var gclidValue = whateverValue;

if (window.location.href === "http://www.example.com") { 
   url = "http://www.example.com?" + gclidValue + "=test"; 
   window.history.pushState("", "", url); 
}
```